# pander.lm tables within slidify

Tags: r, slidify, pander

I'm having difficulty in getting *pander* tables to render in a *slidify* document (specifically with a call to `pander.lm`).

For example, the below works

````
```{r panderWorks, results = "asis"}
id <- rep(1:3, each = 2)
condition <- rep(c("A", "B"), 3)
score <- rnorm(6, 10, 3)
d <- data.frame(id, condition, score)

library(pander)
pander(d, style = "rmarkdown")
```
````

[image]

while the following does not

````
```{r panderFails, results = "asis"}
data(iris)
pander(lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris), 
   style = "rmarkdown")
```
````

[image]

Note that I actually can get the first chunk to render correctly without the `results = "asis"` option, but that's worked for me in the past. I've tried changing many options and still no luck. It's also worth noting that I have no problem getting this to render in a standard *rmarkdown* document. It's only within *slidify* that I have issues.

I'm working within the `io2012` framework, with the `highlight.js` highlighter and the `zenburn` highlight theme. I've loaded the `mathjax` widget and the mode is `selfcontained`.

Below I've attached my output from `sessionInfo()`.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What happens outside of R Markdown? When I run `pander(lm(Sepal.Width ~ Species, data = iris), 
   style = "rmarkdown")` in the command line the markdown code for the table correctly outputs. Does it do the same for you?

Comment: Yes, and in fact if I render an R Markdown document with `rmarkdown::render`, it works fine. It's only within slidify that I'm running into issues.